# Dynamic Multi-Dimensional array problem

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code:

```
Module Module1
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim y As Integer = 1
    Dim arr(x, y) As String

    Sub Main()
        x += 2
        y += 3

        For ix = 0 To x
            For iy = 0 To y
                arr(ix, iy) = String.Format("{0}:{1}", ix, iy)
            Next
        Next

        For ix = 0 To x
            For iy = 0 To y
                Console.WriteLine(arr(ix, iy))
            Next
        Next

        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And with it I'm trying to change the upper bound of array dimensions. But I get this error:"Index was outside the bounds of the array". What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the upper-bound of an array like that in .NET. If you need a dynamically sized Array I'd suggest looking at `List` as it allows you to do all of this.

You'll want to do something like:

```
Dim yourStrings AS List(Of List(Of String)) = New List(Of New List(Of String)
```

To convert this to a 2-D Array:

```
Dim maxListLength As Integer = 0
For Each subList In yourStrings
    maxListLength = If(subList.Length > maxListLength, subList.Length, maxListLength)
Next

Dim yourArray(yourString.Length - 1, maxListLength -1) As String

Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim y As Integer = 0

For Each subList In yourString
    For Each str In subList
        yourArray(x, y) = str
        y = y + 1
    Next
    x = x + 1
Next
```

From 2-D to List(Of List(Of String))

```
Dim yourList As List(Of List(Of String)) = New List(Of List(Of String))

For i = 0 To ArrayXSize
    Dim thisXString = New List(Of String)
    For j = 0 To ArrayYSize
       thisXStrings.Add(yourArray(i,j))
    Next
    yourList.Add(thisXStrings)  
Next
```

Comment: +1 Seconded - Even if you need an array afterwards you can just ToArray the list.

Comment: How can I convert 2-D array to list and then convert the list back to 2-D array?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare array with dimension x and y, to use outbound value you have to redim array using redim() command:

[MSDN Redim Command Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y928)

**Example**:

```
Dim intArray(10, 10, 10) As Integer
ReDim Preserve intArray(10, 10, 20)
```

Comment: I want to be able to change any dimension upper bounds, but ReDim don't allow it.

Comment: Yes, redim allow you to redi each dimension ... ReDim Preserve intArray(10, 20, 20) for example modify second and third dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ReDim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28VS.90%29.aspx) to reallocate memory as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I made this by myself:

```
   Private Function MultiReDim(ByVal a As Array, ByVal dimOne As Short, ByVal dimTwo As Short) As String(,)
        Dim newArr(dimOne, dimTwo) As String
        For x = 0 To newArr.GetUpperBound(0)
            For y = 0 To newArr.GetUpperBound(1)
                If x <= a.GetUpperBound(0) AndAlso y <= a.GetUpperBound(1) Then
                    newArr(x, y) = a(x, y)
                Else
                    newArr(x, y) = Nothing
                End If

            Next
        Next

        Return newArr
    End Function
```

It works with 2D arrays, but can be modified to work with unlimited number of arrays by adding a ParamArray of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when this syntax was introduced, but you can define an array with a dynamic size using:

```
Dim arr As String(,) = New String(x,y){}
```

or simply

```
Dim arr = New String(x,y){}
```

or using the original example

```
Module Module1

    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim y As Integer = 1
    Dim arr(x, y) As String

    Sub Main()
        x += 2
        y += 3

        arr = New String(x,y){}

        For ix As Integer = 0 To x
            For iy As Integer = 0 To y
                arr(ix, iy) = String.Format("{0}:{1}", ix, iy)
            Next
        Next

        For ix As Integer = 0 To x
            For iy As Integer = 0 To y
                Console.WriteLine(arr(ix, iy))
            Next
        Next

        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

(not tested).

I think this syntax is preferable to the old (VB6 style) ReDim statement.