# VBA Multidimensional dynamic array?

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic

I don't know how to create a dynamic multidimensional Array. At present i have declared my array as `Dim fArr(0 To 4, 0 To 9)`. it is always (0 to 4) in one dimension but other dimension (0-9) is always variable so how do i do it?.

I populate my array like this example

```
     Select Case fTyp
         Case Is = "A"
             fArr(0, aRow) = j
         Case Is = "B"
             fArr(1, aRow) = j
         Case Is = "C"
             fArr(2, aRow) = j
     End Select
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the second dimension dependent on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Multi-Dimensional array problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344990/dynamic-multi-dimensional-array-problem)

Comment: just before your loop `redim farr(4,x) as variant` x is the variable that you use in your for loop `for arow = 0 to x`. so what ever you have in place of x in your for loop put that same thing in for x in the redim. Just like @AlexWeber stated.

Comment: Just an unrelated side note, wouldn't `Case "A"` be simpler than `Case Is = "A"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ReDim` to create a dynamic amount of dimensions in an array. Firstly, you must dim your array in the following way:

```
Dim fArr() as String ' Or whatever datatype you want
```

Then, when you're ready to enter the dimension of the Array, you use a ReDim.

```
ReDim fArr(4, VBAVariable) as String 'Or whatever datatype you want
```

You can ReDim multiple times. [Check out this article for extra features that ReDim has.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

Comment: at present it is like this